# AND Condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have a List of Customers:

```
List<customer> customerList;
```

I wants to get just the customers that have Country="India" and Status="A".

I tried this:

```
List<customer> customerList=customerList.Where(p=>p.Country.Equals("India") && p.Status.Equals("A")).ToList();
```

and

```
List<customer> customerList=customerList.Where(p=>p.Country.Equals("India")).Where(p=>p.Status.Equals("A")).ToList();
```

But neither returned anything.

If I divide the condition like the below example then the records are being fetched correctly.

```
List<customer> customerList=customerList.Where(p=>p.Country.Equals("India")).ToList();
customerList=customerList.Where(p=>p.Status.Equals("A")).ToList();
```

I wants to know how to filter the objects using an AND Condition in a single query.

Could anyone tell, Is there any good way rather than calling where condtion.

Comment: Are you sure there's at least one item that satisfies both the conditions ? Your first 2 queries seem correct to me...

Comment: Show your test data as the 2 linq statements would appear to be right on face value.

Comment: Are `Country` and `Status` string variables, or are they of some other type?

Comment: Could you please consider marking an answer correct or even responding at all?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `.Equals` in this case. Use the equality operator (==).

```
customerList.Where(p=>p.Country == "India" && p.Status == "A").ToList();
```

Jon Skeet Article  -  [When should I use == and when should I use Equals?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx)

> For value types, I'd normally use == for easier-to-read code. Things
>   would get tricky if a value type provided an overload for == which
>   acted differently to Equals, but I'd consider such a type very badly
>   designed to start with.

However, you definitely need to make sure your list is actually populated.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected, so I don't know what you were doing, but your original approach was correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    public class Customer {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var list = new List<Customer>();
            list.Add(new Customer() { Country = "India", Status = "A" });
            list.Add(new Customer() { Country = "USA", Status = "A" });

            var results = list.Where((c) => c.Country == "India" && c.Status == "A");

            if (results.Any()) {
                Console.WriteLine(results.First().Country);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```